# С++ видеоуроки. Есть ли хорошие? Для чайника.

Tags: java, c++, видео

Доброго времени суток. Недавно начал изучать программирование, сейчас на этапе базового ознакомления и выбора языка. Сейчас мой выбор пал на С++. Скажите, существуют ли хорошие видеоуроки по данному языку? Хотим занятся с другом именно С++. Заодно, если не сложно, опишите в чем его достоинства и что на нем можно вообще делать. В отличии от той же Java. И что бы из этих двух вы посоветовали?

Comment: ах да, что вообще нужно для работы? Где взять компилятор?

Comment: Учить С++ по видеоурокам, по моему не лучший вариант. Только время зря потеряете.

Comment: Точно, не занимайтесь ерундой. Берите хорошие книги и вперед, "учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться"

Comment: @uranium вместо "С++" можно любую дисциплину вписать, даже не айтишную.

Comment: А почему? Насколько я понял, видеоуроки это достаточно просто и понятно. Конечно же я их буду использовать для изучения базовых вещей. После читать книги.

Comment: Это ерунда, посмотрел и забыл. Надо видеоуроки -- на youtube.com, там они есть. Но вообще я не знаю ни одного человека, который бы выучил язык, пользуясь видеоуроками, но не пользуясь книгами, а наоборот -- практически все. В общем, не рекомендую. А последний вопрос уже когда-то озвучивался, но замечу: Java немного легче (это только ИМХО).

Comment: +1 за то, что видео-уроки не лучший способ. Как раз азы должны постигаться или лекциями (что не то же само что видеоуроки), или книгами + обязательно с разбором кода и написанием своего. Имхо книгами лучше.
Лукавить не буду, но те видеоуроки которые я видео проходят в формате "напишите это, компильните это и вы получите то".

Comment: Никаких видео-уроков, только книги и много практики. Причем, не абы какие, а такого уровня:

 -  [Бьерн Страуструп. Язык программирования С++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/85559/)
 - [Герберт Шилдт. Полный справочник по C++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1498452/)

И избегайте всяких "Учим С++ за 21 час".

Comment: Спасибо. Мне просто было интересно изучить базовые вещи именно по видео, так как часто там всё четко. У меня уже есть несколько проектов, так что я бы пробовал всё равно ответвляться от видео. Спасибо большое, скачал книги, щас буду начинать чтение!

Comment: >И избегайте всяких "Учим С++ за 21 час".

 Такой нету. Есть только за 21 день и за 24 часа. А чем не нравится эта книга? Я с ней C++ очень быстро изучил. Не вижу ничего в ней плохого. Там есть всё что нужно: и вопросы, и упражнения, и примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Visual Studio Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso) - тут iso.
- [С++ для начинающих](http://prog-school.ru/products/cpp_start/) - тут уроки (бесплатно).

Comment: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2615137 - тут очень много книг по C++

Answer (score 6):

Могу только посоветовать аудиокнигу по с++ от Бьерна Страуструпа.

Comment: Тонко)


.

Comment: Обалдеть...

Comment: Логично... Вот и ответ))

Answer (score 2):

Для обучения C++ могу посоветовать легковесный и достаточно простой компилятор - Dev C++ compiler. Сам набираю в нём учебные примеры программ. Скачать можно [по этой ссылке](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html.)

Comment: это не компилятор, а IDE, который, кажется 10 лет уже не развивается. Кроме того, как раз по вашей ссылке, домен-то у них и помер. Печально. Попытки заменить его - http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.ru/ но и там не так много обновлений.

Answer (score 0):

Канал преподавателя МФТИ (кажется) - Тимофея Хирьянова. Например, его курс [ООП на C++14](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRDzFCPr95fItmofHO4KuGjfGtbQtEj-x) (хоть в названии и ООП, начинает с самых-самых основ) - Лучше не видел в рунете. Там же будет рассказано о главных достоинствах языка. Вкратце: если вам нужна очень-очень сложная программа, очень большая(десятки и сотни тысяч строк кода) и достаточно шустрая, кроме C++ с её адекватным созданием маловероятно справится какой другой язык.

Comment: вообще-то не стоило отвечать на вопрос, который явно подлежит закрытию.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте wxDev C++
[link text](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/?q=node/4)

Answer (score -2):

Если у вас склад ума программистская, то выбор единственно правильный. Что можно сделать/написать на С++? Все что мы видим на экранах ВСЕХ устройств, которые имеют ЭКРАН! ну там плюсминус...
Если найдете "Керниган и Риччи. Язык программирования Си" для начала был бы идеальным вариантом!